# Is mms:// URL supported over Media Foundation?

Tags: winapi, directshow, mms, windows-media-player, ms-media-foundation

I am running Media foundation sample example MFPlayer to render the URL mms://.

this is getting failed with error code `MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE`.

In GetMajorType of this Sample, type is coming as `MFMediaType_Image` instead of `MFMediaType_Video`.

1. Any reason why it coming as `MFMediaType_Image` even it is a video file?
2. If it come as `MFMediaType_Image`, how to handle it? I have tried using same code what

it is using for rendering video but got failed with ERROR `0xc00d5214` (`MF_E_TOPO_UNSUPPORTED`).

1. If I play same mms:// in wmplayer, it does not use Media Foundation, it uses direct show to play the same. in direct show it uses wmrender source filter which i cant use as there is no information how to use that. What actually this wmrender source filter does? How can I use/create the same in my application?
2. I tried using topoedit for rendering the same. it throws error stating Invalid media type. I  have read MMS protocol [is supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in media Foundation, than why it is getting failed in topoedit?

Answer (score 0):

For starters:

- [Microsoft deprecated MMS in favor of RTSP (TCP/UDP port 554) in 2003 with the release of the Windows Media Services 9 Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server).
- [Media Foundation doesn't support MMS either, and it likely never will.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/4420bf19-71ce-4a00-9b3b-f441f8d61c63/)
- [What is the official way to render "mms://..." url in Windows 7?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/6e9157ef-8f7c-422c-b865-245c0ebf9e16)

When you play mms:// in Windows Media Player, the filter graph looks like this:

[image: mms:// on WMP]

The fact that WMP uses DirectShow tells that it was unable to set up playback via Media Foundation. CLSID of the source filter on this graph is not public, it is an internal class of Windows Media Player: not documented, not even available for third party applications.

This leaves you two options:

1. [WM ASF Reader Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. Your custom source filter based on [WM Format SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> I have read MMS protocol is supported in Media Foundation

The MSDN article says mms:// URLs are accepted to negotiate RTSP/HTTP protocol (where and if available!) via rollover.

Comment: Hi Roman, Thanks for the quick reply. Just want to confirm one thing in Windows Media Player if we play mms:// it works over windows 7. There Microsoft uses Direcshow Filter "WMRenderer Source Filter" which is unavailable outside. Microsoft says it is wrapper around WM ASF Reader Filter. How Can I use/write WMRender Source Filter for my application? - Sharad